# is there other way to source iframe value?

Tags: php, mysql, iframe

is there other way to use iframe for showing the retrieved mysql database query result?

i have these codes now but it's not working,

```
<iframe id="editor" style="width:500px; height:300px;" value="<?=$textContent?>"></iframe>
```

but when i tried it on textarea, it shows the query result.

```
<textarea value="<?=$textContent?>"> </textarea>
```

here's my database query if it would be helpful,

```
<?php 
// Connect to server and select database.

$query="SELECT * FROM text_tb WHERE textID ='".$textID."'"; 
$result=mysql_query($query);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
    $textID = $row['textID'];
    $textContent = $row['textContent'];
    } 
?>
```

thank you for the help.

Comment: Why exactly do you want to use an iFrame to show content? iFrames are for displaying content that exists on a different url - this I presume is why it's not working...

Comment: P.S. Neither `<iframe>` nor `<textarea>` have `value` attributes.

Comment: it works fine on textarea,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the PHP code is running on the same page as the iFrame you want, you are going to have to use JavaScript to "inject" the HTML into it.

```
<?php 
// Connect to server and select database.

$query="SELECT * FROM text_tb WHERE textID ='".$textID."'"; 
$result=mysql_query($query);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
    $textID = $row['textID'];
    $textContent = $row['textContent'];
} 
?>

<iframe id="editor" style="width:500px; height:300px;"></iframe>

<script>
window.onload = function(){
    window.frames.editor.document.body.innerHTML = <?=json_encode($textContent);?>;
}
</script>
```

You can also put that PHP code in a different page, and set the iFrame's "src" to that URL.

*results.php*

```
$query="SELECT * FROM text_tb WHERE textID ='".$textID."'"; 
$result=mysql_query($query);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
    $textID = $row['textID'];
    $textContent = $row['textContent'];
}

echo $textContent;
?>
```

*main page*

```
<iframe id="editor" src="results.php" style="width:500px; height:300px;"></iframe>
```

Comment: hello there, i find these very helpful and i would most probably want to use the injected JavaScript. but, it still doesn't show my database results. i likely use your code along with the set of codes i'll post above. i forgot to mention that i use iframe for editing the database value.

Comment: @zeroSeven: Why are you using an iframe?  There's gotta be a better way.

Comment: please check this, [link]http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial198_Creating-a-Rich-Text-Editor-using-JavaScript.html